# How to request JSON with body and header in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I had tried with the following code for the request but result with 400 error.
API consists of header and body. Header had two fields that are "Authorization" and "Content-Type". Body format is added to params below.

[image]

[image]

```
    func file( sender: abc){

        let baseUrl = "url”

        let params: [String : Any] = [
            "profile": [
                “Type": [
                    " Real Estate",
                    "Estater",
                    "Construction",
                    "Entertainment"
                ],
                "Size": [
                    "large",
                    “small”
                ],
                "Level": [
                    “A”,
                    “B”
                ],
                “Name” : [
                    “John”,
                    “Harry”
                ]
            ]
        ]

        let header = [
            "Authorization" : "bearer e2ff3aa3-63a3-41d1-bc5a-3e8c88adeaaa",
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        ]

//        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:baseUrl)!)
//        request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
//        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
//        request.addValue("bearer e2ff3aa3-63a3-41d1-bc5a-3e8c88adeaaa", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
//        let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params as Any, options:JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
//        
//        request.httpBody = data

        Alamofire.request("\(baseUrl)", method: .post, parameters: params, headers:header).responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request ?? "no request")  // original URL requ est
            print(response.response ?? "no response") // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data ?? "no data")     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
            print(response.response?.statusCode ?? "noCode")

            if(response.response?.statusCode != nil){
                switch response.response!.statusCode {
                case 200:
                    print("Success")
                    let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
                    print(json)
                    sender.onSuccessCall()
                case 400:
                    print("Error in authentication")
                case 401:
                    print("Error authentication object was not found")
                default:
                    print("dEfault")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help to slove on this problem.

Comment: we don't know what your api wants you are doing your job

Comment: I just want JSON data through post request but it says 400 error. Is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: Without knowing what your API expects, we can't help. Please include a successful request in your question, even it is not from swift (i.e. a Postman request, curl request, etc.).

Comment: if error appeaars in response not before even seding data we can not help, too little information

Comment: please try to use my code see it's working perfect for me i have tested with my magento api

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, The correct way added below.

```
   func file( sender: abc){

    let params: [String : Any] = [
        "profile": [
            “Type": [
                " Real Estate",
                "Estater",
                "Construction",
                "Entertainment"
            ],
            "Size": [
                "large",
                “small”
            ],
            "Level": [
                “A”,
                “B”
            ],
            “Name” : [
                “John”,
                “Harry”
            ]
        ]
    ]

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:”url string”)!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    request.setValue("bearer 5bac059b-eb2b-4e1b-914a-9de5b6a58577", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params as Any, options:JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

   let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    print(json!)

    request.httpBody = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request ?? "no request")  // original URL requ est
        print(response.response ?? "no response") // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data ?? "no data")     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
        print(response.response?.statusCode ?? "noCode")

        if(response.response?.statusCode != nil){
            switch response.response!.statusCode {
            case 200:
                print("Success")
                let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
                print(json)
                sender.onSuccessCall()
            case 400:
                print("Error in authentication")
            case 401:
                print("Error authentication object was not found")
            default:
                print("dEfault")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this code

```
            let urlString = String(format : "Your URL" )


           let params: [String : Any] = [
                "profile": [
                    "Type": [
                    " Real Estate",
                    "Estater",
                    "Construction",
                    "Entertainment"
                    ],
                    "Size": [
                    "large",
                    "small"
                    ],
                    "Level": [
                    "A",
                    "B"
                    ],
                    "Name" : [
                    "John",
                    "Harry"
                    ]
                ]
            ]

            print(params)

            let url = URL(string: urlString)!



  let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

    let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    if let json = json {
        print(json)
    }

    let jsonData = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue);



           var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("bearer e2ff3aa3-63a3-41d1-bc5a3e8c88adeaaa",forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            request.httpBody = jsonData

            Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
                (response) in

                switch response.result {
                case .success(let JSON):
                    print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")



                    break

                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                    //callback(response.result.value as? NSMutableDictionary,error as NSError?)
                    break
                }


                }
                .responseString { response in

                    print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime we need **URLEncoding.httpBody** type for post method hope it may help you and

```
 let headers = [
                   // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" // try this if its ok then use this otherwise use  "application/json" 
                    // "Content-Type" : "application/json" 
                ]
            let parameters = [

                ]

            Alamofire.request("urlString", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

                switch(response.result) {
                case.success(let data):
                    print("success",data)
               case.failure(let error):
                    print("Not Success",error)
                    self.view.makeToast(message: "Server Error!!")
                }

            }
```

Comment: and do u put "Authorization" : "bearer e2ff3aa3-63a3-41d1-bc5a-3e8c88adeaaa" in headers with content-type and tried this

Comment: Yes, I tried it but not work. I also tried with this code  request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type"        request.addValue("bearer e2ff3aa3-63a3-41d1-bc5a-3e8c88adeaaa", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization"

Comment: go to alamofire github and try from their to change urlEncoding type , their are reference about urlEncoding , sometimes our urlEncoding doesn't seems to work with post method type

Comment: **let params :Parameters = [ ]** try this in once in parameter:[String : Any]

Comment: I think its problem in the header request.

Answer (score 0):

Use **URLConvertible** type url in baseUrl

Solution is below:

```
func file( sender: abc){

        let baseU = URL(string:"url")
        let baseUrl = baseU as! URLConvertible

        let params: [String : Any] = [
            "profile": [
                "Type": [
                " Real Estate",
                "Estater",
                "Construction",
                "Entertainment"
                ],
                "Size": [
                "large",
                "small"
                ],
                "Level": [
                "A",
                "B"
                ],
                "Name" : [
                "John",
                "Harry"
                ]
            ]
        ]

        let header = [
            "Authorization" : "bearer e2ff3aa3-63a3-41d1-bc5a-3e8c88adeaaa",
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        ]

        //        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:baseUrl)!)
        //        request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
        //        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        //        request.addValue("bearer e2ff3aa3-63a3-41d1-bc5a-3e8c88adeaaa", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        //        let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params as Any, options:JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        //
        //        request.httpBody = data

        Alamofire.request(baseUrl, method: .post, parameters: params, headers:header).responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request ?? "no request")  // original URL requ est
            print(response.response ?? "no response") // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data ?? "no data")     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
            print(response.response?.statusCode ?? "noCode")

            if(response.response?.statusCode != nil){
                switch response.response!.statusCode {
                case 200:
                    print("Success")
                    let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
                    print(json)
                    sender.onSuccessCall()
                case 400:
                    print("Error in authentication")
                case 401:
                    print("Error authentication object was not found")
                default:
                    print("dEfault")
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sakir Sherasiya .I try it but doesn't work.

Comment: after API called.

Comment: that's i know. I mean if pass wrong json then you get right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149591/discussion-between-sakir-sherasiya-and-kushal-shrestha).